# Developer Console: Android Security Alert libpng using old version cocos2d-x 2.2.6 game

Tags: cocos2d-x, android-security, cocos2d-x-2.x

Developer console is showing security alerts on all of my cocos2d-x v2.x games with detail of using old libpng.

In cocos2d-x v2.2.6, I have found libpng two files **png.h** & **pngconf.h** with v1.2.46 and as resolution is suggested to use 1.2.56 latest version for this one.

I have submitted a build with these two updated files to see if that was the resolution. Will post if got SUCCESS.

Please if anyone have found other solution, then share.

Comment: Solution worked. Just you need to update two files of libpng v1.2.56 in "cocos2dx>platform>thirdparty>android>prebuild>libpng>include" folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution didn't work out at all. Found this link below.

http://www.bengigi.com/cocos2d-x-2-x-android-libpng-vulnerability-fix/